# How to prove that $f(z)$ is bounded if we know that $\lim\limits_{|z|\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}{z}= 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

Knowing that $f(z)$ is analytic on the entire complex plane and that $\lim\limits_{|z| \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z} = 0$.
How do I prove that $f(z)$ have is bounded ? Meaning there exists a real number $M$ such that for every $z, |f(z)|< M.$

Comment: Look at the Cauchy integral formula for the derivative and higher-order derivatives of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: Another way is to look at the Laurent Series of $t f(1/t)$ at $t=0$. The above relationship clearly isn't held for non-constant polynomials, so if $f$ isn't constant, then it must be an entire non-polynomial, so it must have an essential singularity at $ z = \infty$. But we know by the Laurent series $f(z)/z$ is also non-polynomial, so $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f/z = 0$ contradicts that the image of $f(z)/z$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ near $\infty$, so $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb N$, then$$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D(0,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz$$and therefore $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ if $n>1$. So, there are $a,b\in\mathbb C$ such that $(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):f(z)=az+b$. But, since $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f(z)}z=0$, $a=0$. So, $f$ is actually constant.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond @José Carlos Santos, you wrote: "if n>.". what n should be bigger than?

Comment: Typo. I meant $n>1$. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have two questions. 1. How do you know that for n>1 the n derivative of f(z) is 0? And why would n = 1 be different from zero ? 2. How do you know that f(z) is a polynomial?

Comment: 1. $\left\lvert\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D(0,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz\right\rvert\leqslant\sup_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\frac{R\lvert f(z)\rvert}{R^{n+1}}\sup_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\frac{\lvert f(z)\rvert}{R^n}\to0$. 2. Since $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ when $n>1$ and $f$ is entire, $(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z$.

Comment: One last question, wouldn't the limit as R approach infinity will be zero when n = 1. Because in your answer you wrote that this limit will approach zero for n > 1, and then I need to do further check in order to show that the first derivative is zero. So why is the limit not true for n=1?

Comment: Yes, it is also $0$ when $n=1$. I missed that.

Comment: Great now everything is clear, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $f(z)$ is entire, so is 
$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}$$

Next, it is easy to see that 
$$\lim_{z \to \infty}g(z)=0$$
which implies that $g$ is entire and bounded, thus constant. There fore, the exists some $C$ such that $g(z)=C \forall x$.

Finally,
$$0= \lim_{z \to \infty} g(z)= C$$